# How to enable spellcheck for all texts on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to enable spellcheck for all texts on a page?

I mean, even if the text is not editable?

I made some search and I found a way to deactivate it on the editable text. But no way to activate it on non-editable text.

I also saw that if we activate `contenteditable`, then we click on the div with `contenteditable` attribute, and then we go out, the underlined text stay underlined (even if we delete the `contenteditable` attribute with javascript).

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this problem? Paste the relevant parts of your code here and explain why it doesn't work (i.e., what you expect it to do and what it actually does.)

Comment: I tried to add spellcheck="true" on all my div which contains text, but it didn't work..

Comment: Isn't this already your workaround? _I also seen that if we activate contenteditable, then we click on the contenteditable div, and then we go out, the underlined text stay underlined (even if we delete the contenteditable attribute (with js) )_ If you remove the attribute the user can't edit it anymore

Comment: I wan't to be able to see the underlined errors without text editing. There is perhaps a way to trick the user by entering all contenteditable div, then go out, remove the contenteditable attribute, and the errors stays unerlined ?!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/pdRgr/ works for me in Chrome 35

Comment: You might benefit from providing more context here. *Why* do you want to point out your spelling errors to your users?

Comment: @Spokey you get the spell-check text ornaments? Doesn't show up for me in Firefox 30.0

Comment: Yes @Spokey !! Is what I want !!

Comment: I seems very unlikely to find a workaround that works in each browser. You may need a spell check API that highlights the wrong written words

Comment: It works on opera & chrome but not on mozilla & ie.

Comment: @Spokey: That's nice hack/trick :) Am surprised that works!

Comment: @Spokey you can post your comment as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From the W3.org HTML [`spellcheck` spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#attr-spellcheck):

> User agents must only consider the following pieces of text as
>   checkable for the purposes of this feature:
>
> - The value of input elements whose type attributes are in the Text, Search, URL, or E-mail states and that are mutable (i.e. that do not have the readonly attribute specified and that are not disabled).
> - The value of textarea elements that do not have a readonly attribute and that are not disabled.
> - Text in Text nodes that are children of editing hosts or editable elements.
> - Text in attributes of editable elements.

Anything that doesn't fall into this category is not markable for the `spellcheck` attribute but I'm sure there are some Javascript projects out there that will meet your needs to spell-check static `div` elements.

Comment: This is interesting. Perhaps a workaround would be to use an enabled textarea (styled) with a lowered z-index and add an overlay?

Comment: @StaticVoid It would probably work, but it's miles from the best practice.

Comment: It work on div's..  
jsfiddle.net/hxQdV/75  and it was not the question. The question was must "Enabling spellcheck without contenteditable"

Comment: @Superdrac no, it works on `div`s with the `contenteditable` attribute set. Read my answer, and you would understand that you can't enable spell checking without `contenteditable` in a standard `div`.

Comment: @Superdrac what are you talking about? I never said anything regarding `textarea` or `input`.

Comment: @Superdrac there's no discussion here of `textarea` or `input` at all.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little late, but if you don't mind temporarily making your page editable, you can do the following:

```
<body contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
    <!-- content -->
</body>
```

I do this in my testing environments, and remove `contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"` during final testing before moving my work to production.

Some caveats:
1) Doesn't work correctly for me in Firefox (I use Chromium instead).
2) You will, in many cases, have to click on an element before it is spellchecked.